# Recursive link loading in WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing an application which contains `Webview`. I found out that `https://m.9gag.com` is loading recursively(forever). So I checked out the source code of `9gag` and they are using canonical link tag.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://m.9gag.com/" />
```

To find out the exact problem, I override `onLoadResource` of `WebViewClient` and it's calling `https://m.9gag.com` repeatedly. Chrome browser can handle this issue but `WebChromeClient` can not. I found this issue in multiple version of `Android (7,6,4.4)`.

How to solve the recursive loading issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the following `setting` works, not exactly sure why!

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)
```